# How to create a pre-dispatch in symfony, which gets called before any module/action?

Tags: php, symfony

As the title says, I'm basically trying to create a pre-dispatch, similar to how it works in `Zend`, but I need it done in `Symfony`.

For example - if someone navigates to a certain module/action, it would run my pre-dispatch first before doing that, and do the same for any module/action.

Would I need to create a plugin for this? Or is this something that I can setup some other way. Unfortunately I didn't find much information about it in the official documentation, so I thought I'd ask on here.

Comment: Their is a preExecute method that will be called before the controllers action?

Comment: Yeah, but that seems to only be for a particular module. What if I want a preExecute for all modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [a filter](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters). I didn't find any documentation for this in sf 1.4 documentation, all there is is [a documentation regarding the filters.yml file](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/12-Filters). Anyway, it works with sf1.4, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

In Symfony2 you should do something like this, because the preExecute method is not available there: 
[How to create a something like Zend preDispatch method in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293075/how-to-create-a-something-like-zend-predispatch-method-in-symfony2/)