# Symfony replace authentication check functionality

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I am somewhat new to Symfony. I need to check if the user is logged in on every page request. I created a login screen and store the IP address, session id, time of login, username, id and a few more variables in the user table as well as in a session variable. Now I have to check many at every page requests for these variables variables. Can someone let me know where to do the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to create a "preExecute" method, i.e. something that is executed before any of your controller actions. Take a look here:
[How to create a something like Zend preDispatch method in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293075/how-to-create-a-something-like-zend-predispatch-method-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has a very advanced security component which you should use instead of rolling your own security. It will save you tons of headaches. Read about this security component here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

I would also suggest that you use the FOSUserBundle, which is a great complement to symfony security and which provides advanced user handling. You can find this bundle here:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

you can check if is granted with IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED or IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY

In the controller you can use the security.context for that the check

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-a-controller