# Symfony2 controller pre or after action

Tags: symfony

I use 3d level domain to any city, like city1.exampale.com, city2.exampale.com.

My route:

```
@Route("/search", name="search", host="{domain}.exampale.com")
```

For all my controllers I detect type of device (desktop, tablet, mobile) and get city data by $domain

How can I use it in one place or any best way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a pre-dispatch in symfony, which gets called before any module/action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394661/how-to-create-a-pre-dispatch-in-symfony-which-gets-called-before-any-module-act)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own logic, you can put into request listener (kernel.request event). But if you haven't, you can use [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle)